# What's a good service design for database entity update/delete

Tags: java, spring, service

I need guidance for designing a service-layout without circular dependencies and unnecessary database updates.

Assume I have a database with two entities, `Factory` and `Product`. A factory has a list of product and each product has a reference to a factory.

```
public class Factory {
    private String id;
    private List<String> productIds;
}
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String factoryId;
}
```

Each of these entities has a repository class that has methods for finding, creating, updating and deleting these entities in the database.

```
public interface EntityRepository {
    public void find();
    public void save();
    public void delete();
}
```

The business logic for finding, creating, updating and deleting is put in service-classes, one for each entity. When a product is deleted, it should be removed from the list in the factory. When a factory is deleted, all products in the list should also be deleted.

```
public class FactoryService {
    public boolean deleteFactory(Factory factory) {
        // Bunch of other things happening

        factory.getProductIds().forEach(productId -> {
            productRepository.deleteProductWithId(productId);
        });
    }

    public void removeProductFromFactory(Product product, Factory factory) {
        factory.getProductIds().remove(product.getId());
        factoryRepository.save(factory);
    }
    ...
}
public class ProductService {
    public boolean deleteProduct(Product product) {
        // Bunch of other things happening
        Factory factory = factoryService.findById(product.getFactoryId());
        factoryService.removeProductFromFactory(product, factory);
        productRepository.delete(product);
    }
    ...
}
```

In order to skip duplicating the code for `// Bunch of other things happening` when deleting a product, I wanted to reuse code in the two services. However, as you can see it creates a circular dependency as factoryService calls productService which in turn calls factoryService when a factory is deleted. Another problem is that when deleting a factory, unnecessary updates are made to the database. This is because when each product is deleted, the product deletion method updates the factory. Even if adding a new function `deleteAllProducts` to the `FactoryService`-class, at least one update will be performed. Since the factory will be deled this is an unnecessary operation.

If I were to redo all of this, what is a better design? What helper-class am I missing? Am I using service-classes the wrong way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do not see any problem with the above mentioned approach. But since you asked, if you were to redo all this - Go pure JDBC route. That will give you more control and simplicity. But I guess we all know the good and not so good things about whenever we have to make a choice. Did I mention we can compare Apples (JPA) and Oranges (JDBC)? I would choose what I find more tasty.

Comment: Just add cascade delete to your db?